# SQLException timeout

Tags: c#, sql-server

Code is below, the problem seems to be a joke that is costing me a large amount of time. Calling this method I make a request and find more or less 4000 records with a field PIVA empty. So I call a function that interrogate a site with the function agm.getPIVA() and sometime find a PIVA there. So I would to update the db but there's a problem, the update request causes a SQLException timeout. As you see, the operation is very short and involve only 1 (one) record. 
Other things? IDAZIENDA is a primary key, the total table has more or less 30.000 rows.
A suspect is that for some reasons I can't use the same connection in this way, but I copied an old function that works, it seems the same thing. The connection string enable MARS, so I'm a confused a little, in theory the problem should not appear.

Any suggestion will be welcomed. Thanks in advance.

```
private void btnUpdateGuideM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
String selectSQL = "SELECT "
        + " AGAZIENDE.RAGSOC,"
        + " AGAZIENDE.IDAZIENDA,"
        + " FROM"
        + " AGAZIENDE,"
        + " WHERE "
        + " AGAZIENDE.IDAZIENDA>@STARTBY"
        + " AND LEN(AGAZIENDE.PIVA)<>11"
        + " AND AGAZIENDE.VALID = 1"
        + " ORDER BY AGAZIENDE.IDAZIENDA";

string updateSQL = "UPDATE AGAZIENDE "
        + "SET PIVA=@PIVA "
        + "WHERE IDAZIENDA=@IDAZIENDA";

using (SqlConnection awConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand noWebLeadsCmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, awConnection);
    noWebLeadsCmd.Parameters.Add("@STARTBY", SqlDbType.Int);
    noWebLeadsCmd.Parameters["@STARTBY"].Value =Int32.Parse(tbStartBy.Text);

        SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, awConnection);
        updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@IDAZIENDA", SqlDbType.Int);
        updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@PIVA", SqlDbType.Text);

        awConnection.Open();
            try
        {
            using (SqlDataReader selectDR = noWebLeadsCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                try
                {
                    while (selectDR.Read())
                    {
                        string  codNazione = selectDR.GetFieldValue<string>(0);
                        string  nomeNazione = selectDR.GetFieldValue<string>(1);
                        string  codRegione = selectDR.GetFieldValue<string>(2);
                        string  nomeRegione = selectDR.GetFieldValue<string>(3);
                        string  codProvincia = selectDR.GetFieldValue<string>(4);
                        string  nomeProvincia = selectDR.GetFieldValue<string>(5);
                        string  codComune = selectDR.GetFieldValue<string>(6);
                        string  nomeComune = selectDR.GetFieldValue<string>(7);
                        string  ragSoc = selectDR.GetFieldValue<string>(8);
                        string  cKompass = selectDR.GetFieldValue<string>(9);
                        int     idAzienda = selectDR.GetFieldValue<int>(10);
                        string  piva = selectDR.GetFieldValue<string>(11);
                        string  formaGiuridica = selectDR.GetFieldValue<string>(12);
                        if (ragSoc.Length == 0) continue;
                        System.Console.WriteLine(idAzienda + " " + ragSoc + " " + piva + " - " + nomeComune + " " + nomeProvincia);
                        lbAzienda.Text = idAzienda + " " + ragSoc + " " + piva + " - " + nomeComune + " " + nomeProvincia;
                        this.Refresh();
                        AcqGuideMDatas agm = new AcqGuideMDatas(25000, ragSoc,);
                        if (agm.getPIVA()=="") // if PIVA has been found continue with the next item in selectDR
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        // Else update the DB
                        updateCmd.Parameters["@IDAZIENDA"].Value = idAzienda;
                        updateCmd.Parameters["@PIVA"].Value = (string)agm.getPIVA();
                        updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("btnUpdateGuidEM_Click - NullReferenceException: " + exception.Message + "\n");
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("btnUpdateGuidEM_Click - InvalidOperationException: " + exception.Message + "\n");
                }
                catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("btnUpdateGuidEM_Click - SqlException: " + exception.Message + "\n"+ exception.ErrorCode + "\n"+ exception.Number);
                }
                catch (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("btnUpdateGuidEM_Click - SqlNullValueException: " + exception.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("btnUpdateGuidEM_Click - SqlException: " + exception.Message + "\n"+ exception.ErrorCode + "\n"+ exception.Number + "\n\n"+ selectSQL);
        }
        awConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

### **POST UPDATE**

Based on your suggestion I tried to add a connection for update as follows.

```
using (SqlConnection updateConnection = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, updateConnection);
    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@IDAZIENDA", SqlDbType.Int);
    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@PIVA", SqlDbType.Text);
    updateConnection.Open();
    updateCmd.Parameters["@IDAZIENDA"].Value = idAzienda;
    updateCmd.Parameters["@PIVA"].Value = (string)agm.getPIVA();
    updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

It doesn't work, I've yet the same problem, timeout. Is it maybe because I'm trying to update a table locked by the preceding SELECT?
Thanks again

Comment: Probably locking isssue.

Comment: Without [MARS](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets) enabled, only one statement can be active on a connection at any given time. Give the `UPDATE` its own connection (recommended), or enable MARS (but be sure to read the article, and the Special Considerations section in particular, before you just flip the switch).

Comment: You are trying to update the table `AGAZIENDE` that you are currently reading, thats a locking issue. A simple workaround would be to fill a `DataTable` with a `SqlDataAdapter`, loop it's rows and update from there. Then there is no lock.

Comment: In effect I enabled MARS in this class, and this is the reason the other method worked.

Comment: I tried  to add a new dedicated connection, it doesn't work so I suppose that while the "while (selectDR.Read())" is working it's impossible to update the table, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update the table `AGAZIENDE` that you are currently reading, that's a locking issue. A simple workaround would be to fill a `DataTable` with a `SqlDataAdapter`, loop it's rows and update from there. Then there is no lock.

Another way, use [`WITH(NOLOCK)`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/):

```
String selectSQL = @"
    SELECT
        AGAZIENDE.RAGSOC,
        AGAZIENDE.IDAZIENDA,
     FROM
        AGAZIENDE WITH(NOLOCK)
     WHERE 
        AGAZIENDE.IDAZIENDA>@STARTBY
        AND LEN(AGAZIENDE.PIVA)<>11
        AND AGAZIENDE.VALID = 1
     ORDER BY AGAZIENDE.IDAZIENDA";
```

Comment: It works! It's doing exactly what I needed. Now I try the other solutions, but really thanks!

Comment: Be very wary of using `NOLOCK` here. The [problems with `NOLOCK` are well documented](https://blogs.sentryone.com/AaronBertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/), and in particular, it may skip or repeat rows when data movement occurs -- exactly the kind of data movement that could be caused by an `UPDATE` on the very same table being scanned, for example. I don't know if there are safeguards in the engine to prevent this from happening on one connection, but I doubt it.